G++ cannot link to instantiated template static method in shared library
I have a simple code that's trying to link to a static method of a class template that's already instantiated in a shared library. This is the code:
#include <sym/rot3.h>

int main() {
    sym::Rot3<float>::FromYawPitchRoll(0, 0, 1);
}

I compile it with:
g++ -I /home/lukasz/anaconda3/envs/anaconda/include -I /home/lukasz/eigen -L/home/lukasz/anaconda3/envs/anaconda/lib -l symforce_gen -v -std=c++14 main.cpp

The compilation step works fine, but there's an error during linking:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJ5lt02.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11a9): undefined reference to `sym::Rot3<float>::FromYawPitchRoll(float, float, float)'

The code for static method in question (Rot3::FromYawPitchRoll) is available in the shared library symforce_gen that I've linked in my invocation of gcc. It can be verified by compiling the main.cpp to main.o and looking up the unresolved symbol for this method inside main.o:
nm main.o | grep -i yaw
U _ZN3sym4Rot3IfE16FromYawPitchRollEfff

This is matching exactly what is available in the shared library I provided:
nm -D /home/lukasz/anaconda3/envs/anaconda/lib/libsymforce_gen.so  | grep -i _ZN3sym4Rot3IfE16FromYawPitchRollEfff
0000000000069430 W _ZN3sym4Rot3IfE16FromYawPitchRollEfff

Why can't the linker see this method?

the order of items on the command line matters, you need to put the library after things that use the library (in this case main.cpp), i.e. change -l symforce_gen -v -std=c++14 main.cpp to -v -std=c++14 main.cpp -l symforce_gen

Mindblowing! Thanks a lot.
